# Marshal.PtrToStringUni() vs new String()?

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, unmanaged, unsafe

Suppose i have a pointer of type char* to unicode string, and i know the length:

```
char* _unmanagedStr;
int _unmanagedStrLength;
```

and i have 2 ways to convert it to .NET string:

```
Marshal.PtrToStringUni((IntPtr)_unmanagedStr, _unmanagedStrLength);
```

and

```
new string(_unmanagedStr, 0, _unmanagedStrLength);
```

In my tests, both calls gives me exactly the same result, but the `new string()` is like 1.8x times faster than `Marshal.PtrToStringUni()`.

Why is that performance difference?
Is there any another functional difference between the both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judging from available source code (Rotor), the System.String(Char*) constructor uses a heavily optimized code path through CtorCharPtr(), it allocates the string with FastAllocateString().  Marshal.PtrToStringUni() follows an entirely different code path, it is written in C++ and looks to be copying the string twice, without the benefit of a "fast allocator".

Clearly, not the same programmer worked on this.  Almost certainly not even the same team since the code fits a different programming model.  The closest manager in common was probably four levels up.

Not sure how that would be helpful, use the fast one.  Mishaps would generate a similar kind of exception on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

The second is not CLS compliant, requires unsafe code and might have undetermined behavior which is why probably it's faster. There's also a need to [pin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(VS.80).aspx) the pointer to the unmanaged address or the garbage collector might reallocate it which leades to a more cluttered code. Unless you've determined that this is a bottleneck for your application you'll probably want to use the [PtrToStringUni](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4x4bfws.aspx) function.