# .NET Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr) vs. new String(char*)

Tags: c#, .net, string, marshalling

What's the difference between [`new String(char*)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y4za026.aspx) and [`Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyf0tzy4.aspx), aside from the obvious fact that one takes `char*` and one takes `IntPtr`? When should I use which?

I remember getting a *really* random access violation that took an enormous amount of time to track down about a couple of years ago when using the constructor, and it went away when I used the `PtrToStringUni`. Maybe that wasn't the real cause, I don't know, but it seemed to be.

I never figured out what the difference was, though. Any ideas?

---

### Edit:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213871/marshal-ptrtostringuni-vs-new-string) has the answer to most of my question; however: is there any explanation for my access violation, or was it because of something else?

Comment: duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213871/marshal-ptrtostringuni-vs-new-string

Comment: @adontz: Oh wow, you're right -- though that doesn't explain the access violation. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the linked answer, I can guess that you didn't pin the pointer to the char*, which caused (at random) to have the GC move the char* while the constructor was still running, causing the access violation. Just a guess :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you can't use pointers without dropping into unsafe code.  char* is an actual pointer.  IntPtr wraps a pointer.

From the msdn you linked:

"If the specified array is not null-terminated, the behavior of this constructor is system dependent. For example, such a situation might cause an access violation."

Is your char[] null-terminated?

Comment: I thought that you weren't using unsafe, but apparently that constructor wouldn't even show up without it.  Edited my answer.